# How to update an iFrame in Visualforce

Tags: iframe, visualforce

I have an iFrame that is similar to the following:

```
<apex:iframe src="http://www.salesforce.com" scrolling="true" height="600" width="100%" id="docframe"/>
```

I would like to use a link on the parent page (that contains the iFrame) to update the content of the iFrame.

I tried using code similar to whats presented in the iFrame Target example on here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp but on my browser (Firefox) it opens a new tab. Even when I copy and paste the example from the preceding link into my visualForce page it insists on opening a new tab in my browser.

Any idea on what I may want to try to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way

1) First define the SRC of your iFrame in apex and implement the reload method:

```java
public with sharing class YourClass {

    // Source var for the iFrame
    public String iframeSource { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public YourClass() {
        // Default value of the frame source
        iframeSource = 'apex/Page1';
    }

    // The method to reload the iframe with another source page
    public PageReference reloadIframe() {
        iframeSource = 'apex/Page2';
        return null;
    }
}
```

2) Now create a command button to reload the iFrame and the pannel to be refreshed:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!reloadIframe}" reRender="theFrame"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="theFrame">
    <apex:iframe src="{!iframeSource}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```